# Data isn't selected from Database with Room

Tags: java, android, sql, android-room

I have the following code:

```
private void onAddClick(){
        String title = mTitleEdit.getText().toString();
        String body = mBodyEdit.getText().toString();
        Note note = new Note();
        note.setTitle(title);
        note.setBody(body);
        noteDao.insertNote(note);
        notes = noteDao.getNotes();
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(notes, getApplicationContext());
        mNotesRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

So, this code should add data to the database, after select it and add to adapter and then add this adapter to `recyclerview`. But data isn't selected from database, so `note` array is always null and I can't understand why. Table `Note` has data (I watched it in `Stetho`). So, there's a problem in select, as I understand.

Here's the methods of DAO interface:

```
@Query ("SELECT * FROM NOTE")
    List<Note> getNotes();
@Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertNote(Note note);
```

So, what's the matter?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after getting the data?

Comment: Yes, but still nothing happens